# Cross-language web workers?

Tags: javascript, dart, web-worker, dartium, cross-language

Is this possible, from say :

*app.js :*

```
...

var w = new Worker("data:application/dart;charset=US-ASCII," + dart_code );

// will this break or continue?
```

Does anyone who uses Dartium (the Chromium + Dart VM browser) do this?

Comment: I haven't seen this done. is JS necessary? you could just use [dart isolates](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21226025/1919627).

Answer (score 0):

Today it doesn't work. (Just tested with dart 1.4)

Actually, all the work done is more on how to bring existing js library or other in dart than the inverse.

to do this (Js in dart) you can use the [dart:js](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-js) module.
This will allow you to use js lib or function in your dart code.